# What is the difference between respond and response

Tags: word-usage

Respond vs Response

What is the different between respond and response? and how to use it in a sentence?

Comment: A quick dictionary check would tell you that response is a noun while respond is a verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respond is a verb.  "Please respond to my question."

Response is a noun.  "I am waiting for your response to my question."

Comment: Thanks for the response @matildalee23